# PHP extract() not finishing before later code needs results

Tags: php

I have some PHP at the top of my page that reads default css values from a database:

```
$query = "
              SELECT 
                width,
                height,
                fontFamily,
                fontSize,
                color,
                backgroundColor,
                lineHeight,
                marginTop,
                marginLeft,
                textAlign,
                borderColor,
                borderWidth,
                boxShadow,
                borderRadius,
                last_url_published,
                color1,
                color2,
                color3,
                color4,
                color5,
                color6
              FROM 
                users
              WHERE 
                id = :id
              ";  
    $query_params = array (
                           ':id' => $_SESSION['user']['id']
    );

//  echo("<br />index.php: query for defaults is: $query");
    try
    {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("index.php line " . __LINE__ . ". Failed to read defaults from users table: "  . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();


    extract($row);      // produces $width, etc. 

//  echo("<br />killing time here");
```

In the HTML I have

```
<body>

.cell_db {
    width: <?=$width?>;
    height: <?=$height?>;
    background-color: <?=$backgroundColor?>;
    border-color: <?=$borderColor?>;
    border-width: <?=$borderWidth?>;
    border-radius:<?=$borderRadius?>;
    box-shadow:<?=$boxShadow?>
}
```

What I'm seeing is that if I don't put the

```
         echo("<br />killing time here");
```

line in after the extract($row) statement,  the css values - like width :  don't get assigned.The $width value from the extract($row), for example, is apparently not ready when the css lines are evaluated by  PHP.  But inserting the delay from the echo statement provides the time needed.  Does anyone understand what's going on here and how I can make this work?

Thanks

Addendem:

People below asked to see all of the code from PHP to HTML, so here it is:

```
<?php 
//phpinfo();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include ('functions.php');  // so we can call our showarray()


    // First we execute our common code to connect to the database and start the session

    require("common.php");

//  showarray($_SESSION, "index.php, line " . __LINE__ . " SESSION Data:");


    $_SESSION['landingPage'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];  // login will redirect to here, either index.php or indexX.php, after password matches

    // At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not.

    if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page.

        header("Location: login.php");

        // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it,
        // people can view your members-only content without logging in.

        die("Redirecting to login.php");
    }





// get box default style for this user from the database
// update default styles
    $query = "
              SELECT 
                width,
                height,
                fontFamily,
                fontSize,
                color,
                backgroundColor,
                lineHeight,
                marginTop,
                marginLeft,
                textAlign,
                borderColor,
                borderWidth,
                boxShadow,
                borderRadius,
                last_url_published,
                color1,
                color2,
                color3,
                color4,
                color5,
                color6
              FROM 
                users
              WHERE 
                id = :id
              ";  
    $query_params = array (
                           ':id' => $_SESSION['user']['id']
    );

//  echo("<br />index.php: query for defaults is: $query");
    try
    {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("index.php line " . __LINE__ . ". Failed to read defaults from users table: "  . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    extract($row);      // produces $width, etc. 

    sleep(1);

//  echo("<br />killing time here");


// open_color picker  - in color.js
// open color panel  - in color.js


?>
<!doctype html> 
<!-- HTML5  -->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MyWebsheet</title>



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/GLOBALS.js"></script>  <!-- Load these before editbox.js and color.js so they can see them when compiled  -->
<script src="js/weebly_editbox.js"></script>
<script src="js/color.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.0.s/mqa.toolkit.js?key= Fmjtd%7Cluub2h0z21%2C7a%3Do5-9utaqr"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/reset.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/jquery.Jcrop.css" />



<!-- ***************************************************************************************************** -->
<!--                                                STYLES                                                 -->
<!-- ***************************************************************************************************** -->

<style type="text/css">  
/* style top */

body {      /* style wings  wings style  body color*/



    height:4000px;

    background-color:<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/indexX.php'? 'white' : '#165E3D')?>;  
    background-color:#fff;
    background-color:#d44;  /* change to make sure a new index.php is being uploaded  */
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;  /* keeps everything 10px away from walls  */

}
/*
a {
    cursor : pointer;
}  */

p {
    /*  margin-top: 10px;  */
}


#wrapper {
    width:1024px;
    height:800px;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;                   /* puts left edge of wrapper at mid-point of viewport   */
    margin-left: -512px;        /* shifts wrapper left half of its width  */
    background-color:transparent;
}
.cell_base {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    border-style: solid;
    display:none;
}

.cell_db {
    width: <?=$row['width']?>;
    height: <?=$row['height']?>;
    background-color: <?=$backgroundColor?>;
    border-color: <?=$borderColor?>;
    border-width: <?=$borderWidth?>;
    border-radius:<?=$borderRadius?>;
    box-shadow:<?=$boxShadow?>
}
.cellContent_db {
    font-family: <?=$fontFamily?> ;
    margin-top: <?=$marginTop?>;
    margin-left: <?=$marginLeft?>;
    font-size: <?=$fontSize?>;
    color: <?=$color?>; 
    line-height: <?=$lineHeight?>;
    text-align: <?=$textAlign?>;
}
```

Comment: can you use the `$row` key values in your CSS instead of the extracted variables?

Comment: Using `extract()` is considered bad form in most cases, besides that it's not asynchronous either so it should work fine.

Comment: Every time I see somebody use prepared statements properly, and then use extract on the results, I know that somewhere a kitten has died

Comment: However, killing time should not be necessary: extract should create the appropriate variables which are then available to use from that point onwards

Comment: You need to show the exact code sequence. e.g. where do you run the query, and where do you start building the html. DB calls block, and will not continue execution until the query has completed and returned data. There's no way you could start the query and then start on the html code without the results being available, because that's not how php works.

Comment: That cannot happen, as others have said. So the interesting question becomes exactly what *is* happening?! E.g. if you change the `echo` to `sleep(1)`? Does it still fix the problem? (If not, then the echo is doing something special, not the pause.) Basically I want to see the lines between your PHP code and your HTML code. (Make a minimal example from it if you don't want to show it all.)

Comment: A couple of new data points: First using $row['width'] in the css line has the same effect as the $width from extract. That is, it only works with the echo.  Second using sleep(1) instead of the echo does not fix the problem. It has to be echo. I added all the code from the PHP down to the HTML in the original post.   Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you move the `$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` above the `$stmt->execute`? Also, can you `var_dump($row);` for us?

Comment: Moving the setFetchMode didn't make any differce. var_dump($row) returns    array(21) { ["width"]=> string(3) "250" ["height"]=> string(3) "320" ["fontFamily"]=> NULL ["fontSize"]=> NULL ["color"]=> NULL ["backgroundColor"]=> NULL ["lineHeight"]=> NULL ["marginTop"]=> NULL ["marginLeft"]=> NULL ["textAlign"]=> NULL ["borderColor"]=> NULL ["borderWidth"]=> NULL ["boxShadow"]=> NULL ["borderRadius"]=> NULL ["last_url_published"]=> NULL ["color1"]=> NULL ["color2"]=> NULL ["color3"]=> NULL ["color4"]=> NULL ["color5"]=> NULL ["color6"]=> NULL }

Comment: Thanks. What if you `var_dump($width)` directly after the `extract`?

Comment: var_dump($width)  shows string(3) "250"

Comment: So that's all working fine then, as expected. What if you `<?php var_dump($width); ?>` inside of the CSS? I am aware this shouldn't matter, but somehow you're overseeing something and I'd like to find out where it goes wrong.

Comment: <?php var_dump($width); ?>  doesn't run inside the <style> tags but placing it just before the <style> tag shows the same string(3) "250"

Comment: "doesn't run inside the style tag", so there is your problem, somehow. I do not know why this is the case (it works locally here) so you'll have to try and do some more debugging, to see what's really going on here.

Comment: So you're saying that <style type="text/css">  
<?php var_dump($width); ?>   works for you?  That doesn't work here even when I let the echo("killing time") run.  The problem seems to be related to all the NULLs in the database.  If I set all those fields to sensible values it works without running echo("killing time").

Comment: Yes that works, even with `null` values. It should work, I don't see why it doesn't. Good luck!